# Association problems in between models RAILS 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My models
CAR BRANDS MODEL

```
class CarBrand < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :car_ads
end
```

CAR ADVERTISEMENTS MODEL

```
class CarAd < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :car_brand
end
```

my controller:

```
    def index
        @car_ads = CarAd.all.order("car_ads.created_at DESC")
      end
```

car ads migrations:

```
    class CreateCarAds < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :car_ads do |t|
      t.integer "user_id"
      t.integer "car_brand_id"
      t.integer "car_model_id"
      t.integer "state_id", :limit => 2
      t.integer "vin_id"
      t.integer "year_manufac", :precision => 4
      t.integer "km_age"
      t.integer "price_usd", :limit => 7      
      t.integer "car_tel_number", :precision => 8
      t.float "motor_volume", :limit => 10
      t.string "transmission"
      t.integer "horse_power", :limit => 3
      t.text "description"
      t.boolean "visible", :default => true      
      t.boolean "active", :default => true
      t.string "photo_file_name"
      t.string "photo_content_type"
      t.integer "photo_file_size"
      t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :car_ads, :user_id
    add_index :car_ads, :car_brand_id
    add_index :car_ads, :car_model_id
    add_index :car_ads, :state_id
    add_index :car_ads, :vin_id
  end

  def down
    drop_table :car_ads
  end
end
```

Car brands migratiions

```
    class CreateCarBrands < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :car_brands do |t|
      t.string "brand", :limit => 20    
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :car_brands
  end
end
```

so the problem is that i cant get car brand form car ads, please help,
i wanted to get that like
iterating

```
<% @car_ads.each do |carad|%>
<%= carad.car_brand %>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify CAR ADVERTISEMENTS MODEL

class CarAd < ActiveRecord::Base

```
belongs_to :car_brand
```

end

Modify your controller:

```
def index
    @car_ads = CarAd.all.order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add any reference to CarBrand in CarAd table, just add the  car_ad_id column with a migration like this

```
class AddCarBradIdToCarAd < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :car_ads, :car_brand_id, :integer
  end
end
```

So rails would be able to get the corresponding CarBrand from a CarAd